# Prove of the inequalities vertex and edge coloring

Tags: graph-theory

Prove each of the following inequaliites:

(1) $\Delta (G) \le \chi^\prime(G)$, where $\Delta (G)$ is the maximum degree and $\chi^\prime(G)$ is the chromatic index.

Can anybody help me or give some reference about these inequalities? Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question quite a bit. You may want to have a look at the latex code to familiarize yourself a bit better with it. In particular, you don't need to place dollar signs between every few symbols.

Comment: Manuel's hints are good

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

(3) Take a vertex $v$ with $\Delta(G)$ neighbors, and try coloring the edges incident to $v$. How many do you need just for that vertex ?

(4) Just do what you did for (2).  Color the edges with $\chi'(G)$ colors.  The edges belonging to a particular color class cannot touch each other, so they form a matching.

Comment: That sounds good !  Just make sure you write $\chi'$ instead of $\chi$ in the summation...but aside from this details, that's the right argument.